# Template for problem sets?

Tags: templates

Can anyone provide me with a nice template for math and physics problem sets? I am looking for something that is well-formatted and formal. I am not sure how to make a problem set look very professional but also elegant and artistic.

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at these, but they might be worth trying: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/assignments

Comment: I was hoping for a more intricate design than those from that website.

Comment: In that case, posting more information about your requirements would be helpful. And what would be most helpful is if you could give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with anything that you've tried so far or even a mockup of what you're after. At the very least, 'professional', 'elegant', and 'artistic' seem too vague, as they can be interpreted differently by different people. Also, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I am looking for versatile problem set templates that other people use that I could modify to suit my own needs.

Comment: possibly helpful: [Anyone have some cool/artistic problem set templates?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142660/579), [Comparing packages which facilitate typesetting exercises and solutions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22269/579)

Comment: Are there any news here?